# Data sharing between fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

Here is my situation. I have a `List<Data>` and MainActivity and FragmentViewA, FragmentViewB, FragmentViewC. These fragments share the same data but show it differently.

If one fragment change the `List<Data>` then other fragments needs to be updated.

Since loading of this List is expensive can I store this in MainActivity as a member variable? Then on OnSaveInstance() we will save the `List<Data>`to the bundle and retrieve in onCreate() This way when the activity is reclaimed we don't loose data.

Now MainActivity can implement listeners that will listen for any change in the `List<Data>` and if a change occur then notify other fragments.

Answer (score 1):

you could use a messagebus like otto (https://github.com/square/otto)